# How can export and import partial data of MySQL using php?

Tags: mysql, mysqlimport

I am finding solution for importing from csv file to MySQL table. I am able to understand the logic for exporting data it can be achieved by using WHERE clause mentioning the date range.

But I am confused how to import new data into same table and not to overwrite the existing data.

Explanation-
I receive new data from my client every week say
Week 1 - 100 new records which I inserted by using import facility of PHPMyAdmin
Week 2 - 250 **new records now I stuck how can I append these 250 new record in same table**

Is there any way to do directly using PHPMyAdmin or any way round by using php.

Need Guidance...
Thank you to all advisers in advance.

Regards

Comment: You can simply use phpmyadmin import or SQL interface. Simply type the sql command Insert Into with the data values.

Comment: by doing as you suggested will my old recors safe and they will be not deleted or overwritten by new records

Comment: Using SQL interface it will be 100% safe. Why don't u just check for a small sample table if importing a csv(using import option) again erases or retains ur previous data ?

Answer (score 0):

Using SQL interface it will be 100% safe. Why don't u just check for a small sample table if importing a csv(using import option) again erases or retains ur previous data ?

You can also try this for a sample table:-

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/somefile.csv' INTO TABLE tablename
```